# How to resize pixmap in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to use a custom icon in a QtMessageBox, but can't resize the icon at all. The box shows up fine, but the icon is too large.

I've tried code from a similar question, but it didn't work.

```
QPixmap p(80,80);
p.scaled(80,80); //this doesn't seem to change anything
p.load("checkmark.png");

box->setIconPixmap(p);
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is pointless to scale the pixmap before loading it, scale it afterwards.

```
QPixmap p("checkmark.png");
auto newPixmap = p.scaled(80, 80);
box->setIconPixmap(newPixmap);
```